# python - if-else -list comprehension - assigning values in if

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I need to assign a value from one dictionary to another using python list comprehension;
csv_a , csv_b are two dictionaries. I attempt to do following operation.

```
[[csv_a[i][j] = csv_b[j] if j in csv_b.keys() else ' '] for i in csv_a.keys()]
```

I get syntax error denoting "=".

Please help.

sample data:

```
csv_a = {'logging': {'host': 'logging.com', 'port': '443', 'basepath': '/api', 'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'user': 'abc', 'password': '1234', 'secrets': 0}

csv_b = {'secrets' : {'client_id' : 'abc', 'client_secret' : 'efg'}}
```

expected output :

```
{'logging': {'host': 'logging.com', 'port': '443', 'basepath': '/api', 'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'user': 'abc', 'password': '1234', 'secrets': {'client_id' : 'abc', 'client_secret' : 'efg'}}
```

Comment: post sample data of both dictionaries

Comment: added sample data, thanks

Comment: Please post expected output

Comment: Why not - `csv_a["logging"].update(csv_b)`?

Comment: I will try now and come back . as a intermittent solution, I have created a function and passed two dictionary as parameters to assign the values from one dict to another.

Comment: csv_a["logging"].update(csv_b). is adding the csv_b  is providing following ouput{'logging': {'host': 'logging.com', 'port': '443', 'basepath': '/api', 'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'user': 'abc', 'password': '1234', 'secrets': 0 , 'client_id' : 'abc', 'client_secret' : 'efg'}. it is bit different from the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the values of the `logging` key with the `csv_b` dict.

```
csv_a = {'logging': {'host': 'logging.com', 'port': '443', 'basepath': '/api', 'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'user': 'abc', 'password': '1234', 'secrets': 0}}
csv_b = {'secrets' : {'client_id' : 'abc', 'client_secret' : 'efg'}}
csv_a["logging"].update(csv_b)
print(csv_a)
{'logging': {'host': 'logging.com', 'port': '443', 'basepath': '/api', 'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'user': 'abc', 'password': '1234', 'secrets': {'client_id': 'abc', 'client_secret': 'efg'}}}
```

This should get you the desired output.

Or you could go for a `for-loop`:

```
for k in csv_a.keys():
    csv_a[k].update(csv_b)
```

Comment: instead of hard coding csv_a['logging' ]  , I wanted to dynamically pass that value from csv_a.keys() hence i used list comprehension